# cgcontext drawing - first set of shape is shown, the second exact same set, shifted slightly right is not shown

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Left frame.
CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                 frameWidth,
                                 self.frameHeight));
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:frameBorderColorRed
                                                        green:frameBorderColorGreen
                                                         blue:frameBorderColorBlue
                                                        alpha:frameBorderColorAlpha].CGColor);
CGContextFillPath(context);
CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(frameBorderWidth,
                                     frameBorderWidth,
                                     frameWidth - (2*frameBorderWidth),
                                     self.frameHeight - (2*frameBorderWidth)));
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
CGContextFillPath(context);

// Right frame.
CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(frameWidth + distanceBetweenFrames,
                                     0,
                                     frameWidth,
                                     self.frameHeight));
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:frameBorderColorRed
                                                        green:frameBorderColorGreen
                                                         blue:frameBorderColorBlue
                                                        alpha:frameBorderColorAlpha].CGColor);
CGContextFillPath(context);
CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(frameWidth + distanceBetweenFrames + frameBorderWidth,
                                     frameBorderWidth,
                                     frameWidth - (2*frameBorderWidth),
                                     self.frameHeight - (2*frameBorderWidth)));
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
CGContextFillPath(context);



}
```

The left frame is showing but the right frame isn't. However, if I were to comment out the left frame, the right frame shows. I have also tried drawing the lines themselves as in the docs:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextAddRect

To no avail.

Comment: I have found the problem. I've set the blend mode to clear and did not change it back.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using CoreAnimation since it uses GPU.
Besides the problem is that you close current path by:

```
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

and then try to use:

```
CGContextAddRect
```

As documentation says: "Adds a rectangular path to the current path."

You need to use method below to add another path:

```
CGContextMoveToPoint
```

More detailed information you can read there:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/index.html